# How to simulate directories with a htacess file (mod_rewrite)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

what I try to do is to simulate directories with the help of a htaccess file.
I have a website with a file like this:

http://www.domain.com/filename.php?t=yeah-a-title-2014

Now, I would like to rewrite the URL above to the following:

http://www.domain.com/directory1/yeah-a-title-2014/

If a visitor enters one of the two URLs, he should see the second one in his address bar but the content of the filename.php?t=yeah-a-title-2014 should be displayed.

I have no idea how to realize this.
Any ideas?

Comment: @All close voters: It's perfectly understandable what OP asks here. That *you* don't know what the answer is to the question, doesn't mean that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better known as SEO-urls (search engine optimized), SEF-urls (search engine friendly), fancy urls and a couple more of those terms. The basic problem with these kind of constructions, is that they cause an infinite loop if not implemented correctly, and therefore usually the `THE_REQUEST` trick is used, because `%{THE_REQUEST}` is always equal to the request, even if the url is rewritten, which in turn prevents the external redirect from matching if the internal rewrite matches.

```
#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /filename\.php\?t=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /directory1/%2/ [R,L]
#Change [R,L] to [R=301,L] after ALL rules do what you want them to do, and before your site goes live

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^directory1/([^/]+)/?$ /filename.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your answer helped me a lot to get my code working :)